# How to add functions already defined to another controller

Tags: extjs, extjs5

i have defined a couple of methods in one controller, which i one to factor, and use them in another controller, i tried  :

in the second controller (`Mine.view.DashboardController`)

```
requires: [
            'Mine.view.SettingsMenuController'         
        ],
```

But the methods in the required controller (`Mine.view.SettingsMenuController`) are simply not seen by my `Mine.view.DashboardController`

What's the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the shared methods in a class that extends Ext.app.ViewController  Then create your other controller classes that extend your original class... OO programming....

```
Ext.define("MyApp.ControllerOne", {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.controllerone',
    sharedFunction: function() {
        console.log("shareme");
    }
});


Ext.define("MyApp.ControllerTwo", {
    extend: 'MyApp.ConrollerOne',
    alias: 'controller.controllertwo'
});



Ext.define("MyApp.ControllerThree", {
    extend: 'MyApp.ConrollerOne',
    alias: 'controller.controllerthree'
});
```

Comment: My second and third controllers already extend `Ext.app.ViewController` is it possible to extend multiple classes? or are they already extending Ext.app.ViewController the way you point it out ?

Comment: you need a middle class that extends ViewController... then your classes extend that class.  your shared methods are in the middle class.  In the above example ControllerTwo and ControllerThree both can call the sharedFunction (from ControllerOne).

Comment: THanks very helpful !